# deploy MVC webapp to tomcat issue URI

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

After deploying a WAR file to my local, I can access the index page by "localhost:8080/[WAR file name]/" but cannot access other pages without manually fix the URL by adding "/[WAR file name]/" between "localhost:8080" and controller RequestMapping value.

How to config it automatically adds "/[WAR file name]/" to the URI (not export WAR as ROOT.war)

Comment: Is the problem that links from your rendered HTML pages miss out the /[WAR file name]/ segment?

Comment: Are you using the Thymeleaf template engine and have you included your URLs in the template in th:href="@{[RequestMapping value]}"? As in https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Thymeleaf template engine you need to use the [Link URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) to get the links in your templates rendered properly as relative URLs. So if you want a link in your HTML to (say)

```
<a href="/[WAR file name]/books/list">See all books</a>
```

you need to include it in your template as

```
<a th:href="@{/books/list}">See all books</a>
```

If you like, you can also retain the original href attribute:

```
<a href="/books/list" th:href="@{/books/list}">See all books</a>
```

which may be useful if you are using the Thymeleaf templates outside of the MVC application, for design purposes, say, but it will be overwritten by the th:href value when served by Tomcat.